# Strange-Random OAuth Facebook bot api exception

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

I am sending a payload to facebook bot API something similar to:

```
{  
   "recipient":{  
      "id":"some-recipient-id"
   },
   "message":{  
      "attachment":{  
         "type":"template",
         "payload":{  
            "template_type":"generic",
            "elements":[ ... ]
         }
      },
      "quick_replies":[ ... ]
   }
}
```

The EXACT same payload sometimes succeeds and sometimes throws me an error like this:

```
HTTP 400:

{  
   "message":"(#-1) Unexpected internal error",
   "type":"OAuthException",
   "code":-1,
   "error_subcode":2018012,
   "fbtrace_id":"some-trace-id"
}
```

Can this be related to:
https://developers.facebook.com/status/issues/559896447845433/

Comment: I am just bringing awareness that many users might be experiencing this.

Comment: a lot of users are reporting issues at the moment, just google for "facebook issues" or something similar.